# SAP PowerDesigner Database error

Tags: sql-server, data-modeling, powerdesigner

Since a few days, several of my PowerDesigner users are getting SQL errors each time they try to check in a data model into the repository:

```
'\\SHAREDDRIVE\DATAMODEL_UDS.ldm'
        - Checking out the repository document 'DATAMODEL_UDS'...
        - Comparing the local model with the repository model...
        - Updating the repository document...
Some errors occur during the update of the repository model.
Unexpected error while executing SQL statements in the repository
[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 10.0][SQL Server]The statement has been terminated.
SQLSTATE = 01000
select count(*) from #PMTEMP where SESS=654275492
Unexpected error while updating the repository document.
The check in of the document has been cancelled.
```

Anyone who can help with this?

Comment: It's hard to guess what is going wrong, with this generic error message. "The statement has been terminated". It should not be a locking error, on a temporary table. Maybe the statement is not the actual source of the error. You could suggest to the user, to activate the ODBC trace, before attempting again the check-in.

Comment: Or, following the example of "The IT crowd", "Have you tried turning it off and on again?"... restart the database server?

Comment: I assume there is nothing in the server log? out of log space, out of db space...

Comment: @pascal Unfortunately, I don't have access to the servers. That's the application engineer, and he's unavailable at this moment. So waiting it will be I suppose...

Comment: You can try the part "You could suggest to the user, to activate the ODBC trace, before attempting again the check-in.", which works on the client-side...